# Optional parameter "Id" is same for all nodes in MvcSiteMapProvide

Tags: mvcsitemapprovider, asp.net-mvc-sitemap

### following is my sitemap code :

```
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Partner" controller="Partner" key="Partner" action="ShowPartners" >
  <mvcSiteMapNode title="ISP" controller="ISP" key="ISP"  action="ShowPartnersIsps" preservedRouteParameters="Id" >
    <mvcSiteMapNode title="Operator" controller="Operator" key="Operator"  action="ShowIspsOperators" preservedRouteParameters="Id" >
      <mvcSiteMapNode title="Subscriber" controller="Subscriber" key="Subscriber"  action="ShowOperatorsSubscribers" preservedRouteParameters="Id" >
        <mvcSiteMapNode title="Router" controller="Router" key="Router"  action="ShowSubscribersRouters" preservedRouteParameters="Id" />
      </mvcSiteMapNode>
    </mvcSiteMapNode>
  </mvcSiteMapNode>
</mvcSiteMapNode>
```

### following is my route.config

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "GetPartnerRoute",
            "Partner/ShowPartners/{search}",
            new { controller = "Partner", action = "ShowPartners", Search = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
          "GetISPRoute",
             "ISP/ShowPartnersIsps/{Id}/{Search}",
            new { controller = "ISP", action = "ShowPartnersIsps", Id = UrlParameter.Optional, Search = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "GetOperatorRoute",
            "Operator/ShowIspsOperators/{Id}/{Search}",
            new { controller = "Operator", action = "ShowIspsOperators", Id = UrlParameter.Optional, Search = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "GetSubscriberRoute",
            "Subscriber/ShowOperatorsSubscribers/{Id}/{Search}",
            new { controller = "Subscriber", action = "ShowOperatorsSubscribers", Id = UrlParameter.Optional, Search = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "GetRouterRoute",
            "Router/ShowSubscribersRouters/{Id}/{Search}",
            new { controller = "Router", action = "ShowSubscribersRouters", Id = UrlParameter.Optional, Search = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

---

the id parameters is not same for all node.

in above situation.

each node has different "Id" value. which not similar for every node. by renaming "Id" i can achieve what i expected. but i cant change the name of "Id".
so when i goes to child node which having parameter "Id" it sets similar value to its parent node.

### following is my code after inspect :

Home
         >

```
    <a href="/Partner/ShowPartners" title="Partner">Partner</a>
     &gt; 

    <a href="/ISP/ShowPartnersIsps/268e4984-0923-4db7-8dd3-78564663e4d1" title="ISP">ISP</a>
     &gt; 

    <a href="/Operator/ShowIspsOperators/268e4984-0923-4db7-8dd3-78564663e4d1" title="Operator">Operator</a>
     &gt; 

    <a href="/Subscriber/ShowOperatorsSubscribers/268e4984-0923-4db7-8dd3-78564663e4d1" title="Subscriber">Subscriber</a>
     &gt;
```

---

"268e4984-0923-4db7-8dd3-78564663e4d1" is similar for every node. which should be different.

how can i achieve this. please help

Answer (score 0):

When using `preservedRouteParameters`, the values are "preserved" from the *current request*. By definition that means a route value can only be used for a singular purpose (although that purpose can span multiple nodes).

There are 2 ways to overcome this:

1. Use a different route key for each purpose (`{ispId}`, `{operatorId}`, etc).
2. Instead of using `preservedRouteParameters`, use the default behavior of MvcSitemapProvider`which expects a unique node per`id`. You can build up the parent-child relationships by using a [dynamic node provider](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider).

The first option is more scalable. The second option gives you more control (but only scales to about 10,000 nodes).

Do note that for `preservedRouteParameters` to work right, you need to put all of the ancestor's route values into the current request. So, for example you *must* provide `ispId` for the `Operator` node. Even though your action method may not require it, the parent node `ISP` still does for it to build the URL correctly.

See demos of both of these options here: https://github.com/NightOwl888/MvcSiteMapProvider-Remember-User-Position